# JS var function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please take a look at following code:

```
var test = {

    test2 : {
        variable: 'hello world',

        test3: {
            test4 : test.test2.variable  
        },

        echo : function() {
            alert(test.test2.test3.test4);   
        }
    }

};

test.test2.echo();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RUgA4/)

Why can't test4 access the variable:

```
test4 : test.test2.variable
```

Please feel also free to modify my title, I couldn't find a better one.

Thank you!

Comment: Because the object is not yet constructed by the time you are trying to access its properties.

Comment: scope issue, it's hard to explain so I will let the professionals do it

Comment: Ah okay, how can I fix that? What is the best way to do such things?

Answer (score 5):

`test` is `undefined` at the time `test.test2.variable` is evaluated.

Expressions are evaluated inside-out, so your code does the following in this order:

1. create an object
2. create an object
3. attach a `variable` property to (2)
4. create another object
5. attach a `test4` property to (4) whose value is the result of evaluating `test.test2.variable` (this **fails** because test is not assigned until (1))
6. attach a `test3` property to the first whose value is (4)
7. create a function instance
8. attach an `echo` property to (2)
9. attach a `test2` property to (1) that points to (2)
10. assign (1) to the variable `test`.

You could delay evaluation of (5) by using a getter as below if you can rely on modern browsers and if it's unlikely to be read often or you could assign it after `test` is properly initialized.

```
 var test = { 
   test2: {
     variable: "foo",
     test3: {
       get test4 () { return test.test2.variable; }
     }
   }
 };
```

or to be more backwards compatible

```
 var test = {
   test2: {
     variable: "foo",
     test3: {
       test4: null
     }
   }
 }
 test.test2.test3.test4 = test.test2.variable;
```

Comment: So, what would be the best way? My intend is to set a few default values test, test2, test3, which get used in different functions or plugins and that default values should be modified before.

var bla = { test1: "", test2: "", test3: "", fct : function() { //uses test1, test2 and test3 }};

And here I want to assign values to test1, test2, test3.

Comment: @charihans please see my edit.  You need to delay the evaluation somehow and there are a variety of strategies to do that.

Comment: You mention that expressions are evaluated inside out, but [it appears either this is not true, or I've misunderstood what you mean by "evaluated inside out"](http://jsfiddle.net/Qm6Cd/).

Comment: @zzzzBov, Operands have to be evaluated before operators are applied, so inside-out.  In JS, within an operation, arguments are evaluated left-to-right (modulo a spec bug with `>` and related operators in ES262).  `var x = { x: (function () { console.log(x); })() }` is evaluated inside-out, so although the object is constructed first, it is not assigned to `x` until its properties' values have been computed and the properties attached.  This is specified at http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.5

Comment: @MikeSamuel, I'm not sure I follow your reply. I'm talking about the order in which the values of the properties are computed. If the objects were being constructed inside-out, I'd expect the order to be along the lines of `a, c, b`, but in the example I posted, `a, b, c` is the order in the console.

Comment: @zzzzBov, I think we mean different things by "inside-out" then.  By "inside-out", I mean that the side effect due to the outside (`var x = { ... }`) happens after side effects due to the inside (`...`).

Comment: @MikeSamuel, I took "inside-out" to mean that the innermost literals and expressions were evaluated before their parents. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @zzzzBov, sorry for the confusion.  My statement was pretty trivial since I don't know how much the OP understands about order-of-evaluation, so if you assumed I was saying something profound you would rule out my actual meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Because `test` it isn't assigned yet. The Javascript interpreter first parses the JSON literal on the right and then assigns the value to the `test` variable:

```
var test = {...}
```

To fix it you could do this:

```
var test = {
    test2 : {
        variable: 'hello world',
        test3: {

        },
        echo : function() {
            alert(test.test2.test3.test4);   
        }
    }
};
test.test3.test4 = test.test2.variable;
```

Comment: Ah okay, how can I fix that? What is the best way to do such things?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
I havent explained it since Mike Samuel has given a good explanation.

```
var test = {

    test2 : {
        variable: 'hello world',

        test3: {
            test4 : function (){return test.test2.variable  }
        },

        echo : function() {
            alert(test.test2.test3.test4());   
        }
    }        
};

test.test2.echo();
```